# TextBox shows "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox" when opening PS1 file via .lnk

Tags: wpf, powershell, windows-forms-designer

I made a small application in WPF and powershell using XML for the gui template.
The whole application works fine when i open it with right-mouse click and open with powershell of even when i open it true a .exe file that i made for it.
But when i try to open it with a .lnk file it does not show its velue's but instead it presents me with "System.Windows.Controls.TextBox".

I can not show all of my code due to security reasons but i can on collaborate when needed.

P.s I don't often post on stack overflow, if i did something wrong please let me know.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**In the XML:**

```
[xml]$04Instellingen = @"
<Grid
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="470" Width="852">

    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEEFAFF" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.4"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="291" Margin="32,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="801" Background="{x:Null}">
        <TabItem Header="Algemeen">
            <Grid>
                <Label x:Name="label1_Copy" Content="Benaming:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"/>
                <Label x:Name="label1_Copy1" Content="Ip adres:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="146,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="119"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="ipnaam1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Server1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="ip1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="150,77,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Server1 ip adres" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="ipnaam2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Server2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="ip2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="150,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Server2 ip adres" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="ipnaam3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,144,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Server3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="ip3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="150,144,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Server2 ip adres" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165"/>
                <Label x:Name="label5" Content="Stel hieronder de servernamen en ip andressen in die automatisch op conetiviteid worden getest." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="545"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
     #More code here but is irrelevant#
</Grid>
"@
```

**Code powershell:**

```
$ipnaam1      = $AboutXaml.FindName("ipnaam1") 
$ipnaam1.Text = $global:ipnaam1

$ipnaam2      = $AboutXaml.FindName("ipnaam2") 
$ipnaam2.Text = $global:ipnaam2

$ipnaam3      = $AboutXaml.FindName("ipnaam3") 
$ipnaam3.Text = $global:ipnaam3

$ip1      = $AboutXaml.FindName("ip1") 
$ip1.Text = $global:ipadres1

$ip2      = $AboutXaml.FindName("ip2") 
$ip2.Text = $global:ipadres2

$ip3      = $AboutXaml.FindName("ip3") 
$ip3.Text = $global:ipadres3
```

**Where it gets its velue's from:**

```
function Import-Config {
    #If a config file exists for the current user in the expected location, it is imported
    #and values from the config file are placed into global variables
    if (Test-Path -Path "$loc\instellingen\Config.config") {
        try {
            #Imports the config file and saves it to variable $Config
            $Config = Import-Clixml -Path "$loc\instellingen\Config.config"
            
            #Creates global variables for each config property and sets their values
            $global:ServerBericht = $Config.ServerBericht
            $global:DownloadVan = $Config.DownloadVan
            $global:DownloadNaar = $Config.DownloadNaar
            $global:LogBestandLocatie = $Config.LogBestandLocatie
            $global:InfoTextElias = $Config.InfoTextElias
            $global:ipnaam1 = $Config.ipnaam1
            $global:ipnaam2 = $Config.ipnaam2
            $global:ipnaam3 = $Config.ipnaam3
            $global:ipadres1 = $Config.ipadres1
            $global:ipadres2 = $Config.ipadres2
            $global:ipadres3 = $Config.ipadres3
        }
        catch {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("An error occurred importing your Config file. A new Config file will be generated for you. $_", 'Import Config Error', 'OK', 'Error')
            New-Config
        }
    } #end if config file exists
    else {
        New-Config
    }
} #end function Import-Config
```

**.Config File population**

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Collections.Hashtable</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <DCT>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">ipadres3</S>
        <S N="Value">127.0.0.1</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">LogBestandLocatie</S>
        <S N="Value">C:\temp</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">ipadres1</S>
        <S N="Value">127.0.0.1</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">ipadres2</S>
        <S N="Value">127.0.0.1</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">ServerBericht</S>
        <S N="Value">Er zijn geen netwerk berichten.</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">DownloadNaar</S>
        <S N="Value">C:\maps</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">ipnaam3</S>
        <S N="Value">Ongedefinieerd</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">ipnaam1</S>
        <S N="Value">Ongedefinieerd</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">InfoTextElias</S>
        <S N="Value">Als de app vast lijkt te lopen dan is deze druk aan het werk, Wees geduldig.  (Hier word aan gewerkt)</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">DownloadVan</S>
        <S N="Value">\MAPS-HIER</S>
      </En>
      <En>
        <S N="Key">ipnaam2</S>
        <S N="Value">Ongedefinieerd</S>
      </En>
    </DCT>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

**This is how i call the script from the .lnk**

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File System.App.ps1
```

Comment: Where is the code which populates that value?  When you debug, where does that value come from?  A picture of the UI doesn't tell us much of anything about the problem.

Comment: @artafact - if you can't post your original code, can you create a "minimal reproducible example" that you *can* post? (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Without some example code this question giving very little to go on...

Comment: @Artafact - that's better, but it looks like there's quite a lot of unrelated stuff in the code, which makes it hard to know where to start. It would be helpful if you could post a "minimal, reproducible example" that demonstrates just the specific issue rather than including the entire application (e.g. remove all unrelated controls from the xaml, and provide a cut&pastable script - I had to work out how to convert the [xml] into a xaml window in order to run the sample with ```$AboutXaml=[System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)``` but your code might be doing something different).

Comment: also, test your sample code locally - basically forget everything you know about your application and see if you can recreate the issue using *just* the code you've posted. if *you* can't reproduce it from what you've posted, it's unlikely anyone else will be able to either :-).

Comment: @mclayton Good morning, (UTC +2)
Well i discovered that when i call another .ps1 script from the .lnk and with that script i open my main script it all works perfectly, For example i double click start.ps1 en with start.ps1 i open main.ps1 with ` $loc=Get-Location & "$loc\main.ps1" `
But as you know, Servers don't like or accept opening scripts from scripts, for obvious reasons.
But the code itself works, its the linking of path resolving...